# Cant swap tools in edit mode for hard ops and boxcutter

Tags: hard-ops

Is it possible to quickly switch tools in edit mode for hard ops and boxcutter. Right now the shortcut Alt+W only works for swapping tools in object mode.

When in edit mode, it only goes to boxcutter and doesnt swap to hard ops.

[image]

Comment: Both addons are third-party addons not built-in to Blender so you will have to ask the addon authors that question. This Q&A site can only help with questions about Blender itself.

Comment: In addition to John Eason's comment regarding 3rd party addons, I'll add that YouTube has many tutorials for these particular ones.